# pass parameters containing white space on command line

Tags: cmd, whitespace, exiftool

I would like to pass a parameter containing white space. For example:

```
C:\temp>exiftool.exe -"Region Person Display Name" temp.jpg
```

Can someone please give me direction here? The obvious does not appear to work.

Comment: Your parameter with spaces is getting passed fine for most applications. I suspect it is simply incorrect usage of EXIFTOOL.EXE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what was going on via trial and error. This is not contained in the exif documentation: when passing a tag to exiftool.exe, you need to drop the white space from the tag name. For example, if the tag name is "Region Person Display Name", the code will read:

```
C:\temp>exiftool.exe -"RegionPersonDisplayName" temp.jpg
```

From what I can tell, this 'feature' is not documented.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man, in linux, you just remove the space :

```
$ exiftool -LightSource opencamera2.jpg 
Light Source                    : Daylight
```